# Update sequence on row INSERT

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a primary key set on an id field that uses a sequence to generate numbers as its default value. When inserting records, this works fine and the sequence is correctly updated. However, if I insert records with an id field (e.g. an import from a backup), the sequence is not updated.

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table (
  my_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('my_id_seq'),
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT my_primary PRIMARY KEY (myid)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.my_id_seq
   START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

This updates the sequence:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('Bart');
```

This doesn't:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_id, name) VALUES (12, 'Bart');
```

Causing problems when the sequence hits 12 and I try to insert without an ID.

Is there a good/standard way to do this automatically? I know MySQL does it in its `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (which is way I ran into this problem, I came from MySQL). I looked online and found some ways: using a trigger, or manually updating the sequence after inserting, but many of these resources are quite old. Perhaps version 9.1 has some features to address this?

Comment: The solution is quite simple: don't supply values for auto-generated columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the problem only occurs when importing data into the tables, for example from backups. I have to supply those id's because they are foreign keys in other tables.

Comment: If that is part of an import, running a `setval()` after the import finished is probably the best way to do it: `select setval('my_id_seq', (select max(id) from my_table));` the trigger solution is an overkill in that situation I think (slows down the insert massively)

Comment: If that is the case, exports (especially backups) should contain the `setval()` calls too. `pg_dump` does that, f.ex.

Comment: @pozs: thanks, but I export to Excel and use that same file also to import again. I'll have to create some sort of "finalize import" function that updates all the sequences.

Comment: That would do the job. My answer is more like a general answer, but only do that if you really *need* to; but this case i'm agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. Also consider locking that table for the time of the import.

Comment: You can write a function that goes through all sequences and adjusts them to the current value of the related table. But that requires that you use a `serial` column or an `alter sequence owned by ..` in order to automate that (`owned by` will establish a "link" between the sequence and the column, so that you can find out which column is populated by which sequence using `pg_get_serial_sequence`)

Comment: Instead of just inserting raw data, you can write a function that will insert data using default `insert` without IDs and use `returning id` clause to get added record ID for further references. It is a bit complicated, but is concurrently safe.

Answer (score 5):

That's a known limitation: sequences are incremented during the call of the [`nextval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html) function, which is your default value of your field. When you supply data at `INSERT` to that field, the default value's expression does not evaluates, that's why the sequence's value is not touched.

A workaround is to set up a trigger before/after `INSERT` to manually fix the sequence's value with [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html). But this way you *should* need to set up a trigger on `UPDATE` on that field too, to fix the sequence's value, when you just update some existing id to a higher id.

Another workaround is, that you write a stored function, which can produce an available value for that field & set your field's default value to that function's return value. Someting, like:

```
LOOP
    result = nextval('my_id_seq');
    EXIT WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_id = result);
END LOOP;
RETURN result;
```

But be warned: the default functionality for sequences is safe for concurrent inserts (the current state of the sequence is global - transaction independent). If you supply explicit values to those fields, that won't be the case.